# Formatting a complex nested object in PHP with mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to create a rather large nested object that represents guest data for an amusement park. Essentially, there are 4 categories of genders in the database: male, female, non-binary, and unanswered. There are also 8 age groups, denoted with letters starting from A going till G. Lastly, within each age group there should be a key value pair of zone names (eg food court) with the amount of guests in that zone. You'll note below that the genders array is hard coded to also include an "answered" and "all" category. I need to also have the total for each grouping so that I can calculate the values for these two categories. I hope that make sense.

Ultimately, I need to create an object that looks like this:

```
    "data": {
        "gender_male": {
            "agegroup_A": {
                "Location Not Known": 5,
                "Main Gate Area": 7,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 5,
                "Live! Lagoon": 7,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 4,
                "Private Domain": 8,
                "Thrill Zone": 7,
                "Cabana Suites": 8,
                "Island": 4,
                "Chat Creek": 9,
                "Family Slides": 4,
                "Virtual Village": 1,
                "Unknown Location": 6,
                "agegroup_count": 75
            },
            "agegroup_B": {
                "Location Not Known": 8,
                "Main Gate Area": 8,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 2,
                "Live! Lagoon": 6,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 2,
                "Private Domain": 8,
                "Thrill Zone": 7,
                "Cabana Suites": 3,
                "Island": 3,
                "Chat Creek": 5,
                "Family Slides": 5,
                "Virtual Village": 4,
                "Unknown Location": 7,
                "agegroup_count": 68
            },
            "agegroup_C": {
                "Location Not Known": 6,
                "Main Gate Area": 6,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 3,
                "Live! Lagoon": 1,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 8,
                "Private Domain": 3,
                "Thrill Zone": 3,
                "Cabana Suites": 4,
                "Island": 7,
                "Chat Creek": 3,
                "Family Slides": 7,
                "Virtual Village": 5,
                "Unknown Location": 6,
                "agegroup_count": 62
            },
            "agegroup_D": {
                "Location Not Known": 7,
                "Main Gate Area": 2,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 2,
                "Live! Lagoon": 6,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 3,
                "Private Domain": 6,
                "Thrill Zone": 5,
                "Cabana Suites": 8,
                "Island": 4,
                "Chat Creek": 9,
                "Family Slides": 5,
                "Virtual Village": 4,
                "Unknown Location": 2,
                "agegroup_count": 63
            },
            "agegroup_E": {
                "Location Not Known": 7,
                "Main Gate Area": 1,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 7,
                "Live! Lagoon": 9,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 5,
                "Private Domain": 5,
                "Thrill Zone": 5,
                "Cabana Suites": 8,
                "Island": 2,
                "Chat Creek": 7,
                "Family Slides": 9,
                "Virtual Village": 8,
                "Unknown Location": 4,
                "agegroup_count": 77
            },
            "agegroup_F": {
                "Location Not Known": 8,
                "Main Gate Area": 8,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 6,
                "Live! Lagoon": 4,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 4,
                "Private Domain": 5,
                "Thrill Zone": 6,
                "Cabana Suites": 5,
                "Island": 7,
                "Chat Creek": 6,
                "Family Slides": 9,
                "Virtual Village": 2,
                "Unknown Location": 8,
                "agegroup_count": 78
            },
            "agegroup_G": {
                "Location Not Known": 4,
                "Main Gate Area": 6,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 3,
                "Live! Lagoon": 6,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 9,
                "Private Domain": 5,
                "Thrill Zone": 2,
                "Cabana Suites": 9,
                "Island": 1,
                "Chat Creek": 9,
                "Family Slides": 7,
                "Virtual Village": 7,
                "Unknown Location": 5,
                "agegroup_count": 73
            },
            "gender_count": 496
        },
        "gender_female": {
            "agegroup_A": {
                "Location Not Known": 9,
                "Main Gate Area": 7,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 7,
                "Live! Lagoon": 2,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 6,
                "Private Domain": 3,
                "Thrill Zone": 2,
                "Cabana Suites": 7,
                "Island": 1,
                "Chat Creek": 2,
                "Family Slides": 5,
                "Virtual Village": 2,
                "Unknown Location": 2,
                "agegroup_count": 55
            },
            "agegroup_B": {
                "Location Not Known": 9,
                "Main Gate Area": 7,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 3,
                "Live! Lagoon": 9,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 2,
                "Private Domain": 4,
                "Thrill Zone": 6,
                "Cabana Suites": 5,
                "Island": 1,
                "Chat Creek": 3,
                "Family Slides": 4,
                "Virtual Village": 7,
                "Unknown Location": 2,
                "agegroup_count": 62
            },
            "agegroup_C": {
                "Location Not Known": 9,
                "Main Gate Area": 6,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 4,
                "Live! Lagoon": 5,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 7,
                "Private Domain": 9,
                "Thrill Zone": 5,
                "Cabana Suites": 1,
                "Island": 9,
                "Chat Creek": 2,
                "Family Slides": 9,
                "Virtual Village": 9,
                "Unknown Location": 4,
                "agegroup_count": 79
            },
            "agegroup_D": {
                "Location Not Known": 9,
                "Main Gate Area": 3,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 4,
                "Live! Lagoon": 9,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 3,
                "Private Domain": 5,
                "Thrill Zone": 9,
                "Cabana Suites": 9,
                "Island": 3,
                "Chat Creek": 8,
                "Family Slides": 8,
                "Virtual Village": 9,
                "Unknown Location": 1,
                "agegroup_count": 80
            },
            "agegroup_E": {
                "Location Not Known": 4,
                "Main Gate Area": 5,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 3,
                "Live! Lagoon": 6,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 7,
                "Private Domain": 6,
                "Thrill Zone": 8,
                "Cabana Suites": 5,
                "Island": 1,
                "Chat Creek": 9,
                "Family Slides": 1,
                "Virtual Village": 1,
                "Unknown Location": 5,
                "agegroup_count": 61
            },
            "agegroup_F": {
                "Location Not Known": 7,
                "Main Gate Area": 1,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 2,
                "Live! Lagoon": 5,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 2,
                "Private Domain": 4,
                "Thrill Zone": 9,
                "Cabana Suites": 7,
                "Island": 3,
                "Chat Creek": 7,
                "Family Slides": 6,
                "Virtual Village": 2,
                "Unknown Location": 6,
                "agegroup_count": 61
            },
            "agegroup_G": {
                "Location Not Known": 9,
                "Main Gate Area": 3,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 6,
                "Live! Lagoon": 8,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 2,
                "Private Domain": 4,
                "Thrill Zone": 9,
                "Cabana Suites": 3,
                "Island": 5,
                "Chat Creek": 3,
                "Family Slides": 1,
                "Virtual Village": 3,
                "Unknown Location": 2,
                "agegroup_count": 58
            },
            "gender_count": 456
        },
        "gender_nonbinary": {
            "agegroup_A": {
                "Location Not Known": 5,
                "Main Gate Area": 3,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 8,
                "Live! Lagoon": 4,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 5,
                "Private Domain": 9,
                "Thrill Zone": 4,
                "Cabana Suites": 3,
                "Island": 4,
                "Chat Creek": 8,
                "Family Slides": 4,
                "Virtual Village": 2,
                "Unknown Location": 9,
                "agegroup_count": 68
            },
            "agegroup_B": {
                "Location Not Known": 3,
                "Main Gate Area": 2,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 8,
                "Live! Lagoon": 9,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 6,
                "Private Domain": 8,
                "Thrill Zone": 5,
                "Cabana Suites": 8,
                "Island": 4,
                "Chat Creek": 8,
                "Family Slides": 2,
                "Virtual Village": 1,
                "Unknown Location": 3,
                "agegroup_count": 67
            },
            "agegroup_C": {
                "Location Not Known": 4,
                "Main Gate Area": 9,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 1,
                "Live! Lagoon": 7,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 3,
                "Private Domain": 8,
                "Thrill Zone": 2,
                "Cabana Suites": 2,
                "Island": 5,
                "Chat Creek": 3,
                "Family Slides": 5,
                "Virtual Village": 1,
                "Unknown Location": 6,
                "agegroup_count": 56
            },
            "agegroup_D": {
                "Location Not Known": 7,
                "Main Gate Area": 7,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 4,
                "Live! Lagoon": 5,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 5,
                "Private Domain": 8,
                "Thrill Zone": 2,
                "Cabana Suites": 7,
                "Island": 5,
                "Chat Creek": 3,
                "Family Slides": 6,
                "Virtual Village": 7,
                "Unknown Location": 2,
                "agegroup_count": 68
            },
            "agegroup_E": {
                "Location Not Known": 8,
                "Main Gate Area": 1,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 4,
                "Live! Lagoon": 2,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 4,
                "Private Domain": 2,
                "Thrill Zone": 8,
                "Cabana Suites": 8,
                "Island": 9,
                "Chat Creek": 1,
                "Family Slides": 8,
                "Virtual Village": 2,
                "Unknown Location": 9,
                "agegroup_count": 66
            },
            "agegroup_F": {
                "Location Not Known": 4,
                "Main Gate Area": 4,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 1,
                "Live! Lagoon": 5,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 5,
                "Private Domain": 4,
                "Thrill Zone": 5,
                "Cabana Suites": 2,
                "Island": 6,
                "Chat Creek": 3,
                "Family Slides": 3,
                "Virtual Village": 1,
                "Unknown Location": 9,
                "agegroup_count": 52
            },
            "agegroup_G": {
                "Location Not Known": 1,
                "Main Gate Area": 7,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 2,
                "Live! Lagoon": 9,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 8,
                "Private Domain": 7,
                "Thrill Zone": 4,
                "Cabana Suites": 3,
                "Island": 2,
                "Chat Creek": 4,
                "Family Slides": 1,
                "Virtual Village": 7,
                "Unknown Location": 6,
                "agegroup_count": 61
            },
            "gender_count": 438
        },
        "gender_unanswered": {
            "agegroup_A": {
                "Location Not Known": 1,
                "Main Gate Area": 3,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 9,
                "Live! Lagoon": 2,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 4,
                "Private Domain": 1,
                "Thrill Zone": 9,
                "Cabana Suites": 9,
                "Island": 3,
                "Chat Creek": 6,
                "Family Slides": 9,
                "Virtual Village": 7,
                "Unknown Location": 1,
                "agegroup_count": 64
            },
            "agegroup_B": {
                "Location Not Known": 5,
                "Main Gate Area": 8,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 3,
                "Live! Lagoon": 6,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 8,
                "Private Domain": 4,
                "Thrill Zone": 7,
                "Cabana Suites": 6,
                "Island": 8,
                "Chat Creek": 3,
                "Family Slides": 9,
                "Virtual Village": 6,
                "Unknown Location": 6,
                "agegroup_count": 79
            },
            "agegroup_C": {
                "Location Not Known": 4,
                "Main Gate Area": 5,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 3,
                "Live! Lagoon": 6,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 2,
                "Private Domain": 5,
                "Thrill Zone": 5,
                "Cabana Suites": 1,
                "Island": 1,
                "Chat Creek": 7,
                "Family Slides": 4,
                "Virtual Village": 5,
                "Unknown Location": 9,
                "agegroup_count": 57
            },
            "agegroup_D": {
                "Location Not Known": 9,
                "Main Gate Area": 9,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 9,
                "Live! Lagoon": 2,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 2,
                "Private Domain": 1,
                "Thrill Zone": 6,
                "Cabana Suites": 8,
                "Island": 5,
                "Chat Creek": 9,
                "Family Slides": 5,
                "Virtual Village": 9,
                "Unknown Location": 4,
                "agegroup_count": 78
            },
            "agegroup_E": {
                "Location Not Known": 2,
                "Main Gate Area": 2,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 3,
                "Live! Lagoon": 8,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 4,
                "Private Domain": 8,
                "Thrill Zone": 8,
                "Cabana Suites": 1,
                "Island": 1,
                "Chat Creek": 6,
                "Family Slides": 8,
                "Virtual Village": 4,
                "Unknown Location": 3,
                "agegroup_count": 58
            },
            "agegroup_F": {
                "Location Not Known": 1,
                "Main Gate Area": 6,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 6,
                "Live! Lagoon": 6,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 2,
                "Private Domain": 5,
                "Thrill Zone": 5,
                "Cabana Suites": 5,
                "Island": 5,
                "Chat Creek": 5,
                "Family Slides": 5,
                "Virtual Village": 4,
                "Unknown Location": 7,
                "agegroup_count": 62
            },
            "agegroup_G": {
                "Location Not Known": 4,
                "Main Gate Area": 9,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 1,
                "Live! Lagoon": 1,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 4,
                "Private Domain": 1,
                "Thrill Zone": 6,
                "Cabana Suites": 5,
                "Island": 4,
                "Chat Creek": 5,
                "Family Slides": 1,
                "Virtual Village": 4,
                "Unknown Location": 6,
                "agegroup_count": 51
            },
            "gender_count": 449
        },
        "gender_answered": {
            "agegroup_A": {
                "Location Not Known": 4,
                "Main Gate Area": 3,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 2,
                "Live! Lagoon": 7,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 6,
                "Private Domain": 8,
                "Thrill Zone": 5,
                "Cabana Suites": 4,
                "Island": 3,
                "Chat Creek": 1,
                "Family Slides": 1,
                "Virtual Village": 6,
                "Unknown Location": 8,
                "agegroup_count": 58
            },
            "agegroup_B": {
                "Location Not Known": 5,
                "Main Gate Area": 8,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 6,
                "Live! Lagoon": 3,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 5,
                "Private Domain": 7,
                "Thrill Zone": 3,
                "Cabana Suites": 4,
                "Island": 7,
                "Chat Creek": 2,
                "Family Slides": 6,
                "Virtual Village": 3,
                "Unknown Location": 7,
                "agegroup_count": 66
            },
            "agegroup_C": {
                "Location Not Known": 9,
                "Main Gate Area": 1,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 8,
                "Live! Lagoon": 8,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 7,
                "Private Domain": 8,
                "Thrill Zone": 3,
                "Cabana Suites": 8,
                "Island": 2,
                "Chat Creek": 9,
                "Family Slides": 5,
                "Virtual Village": 1,
                "Unknown Location": 4,
                "agegroup_count": 73
            },
            "agegroup_D": {
                "Location Not Known": 5,
                "Main Gate Area": 4,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 2,
                "Live! Lagoon": 4,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 8,
                "Private Domain": 4,
                "Thrill Zone": 7,
                "Cabana Suites": 4,
                "Island": 4,
                "Chat Creek": 5,
                "Family Slides": 7,
                "Virtual Village": 4,
                "Unknown Location": 2,
                "agegroup_count": 60
            },
            "agegroup_E": {
                "Location Not Known": 8,
                "Main Gate Area": 6,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 1,
                "Live! Lagoon": 4,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 1,
                "Private Domain": 3,
                "Thrill Zone": 6,
                "Cabana Suites": 8,
                "Island": 2,
                "Chat Creek": 8,
                "Family Slides": 3,
                "Virtual Village": 3,
                "Unknown Location": 3,
                "agegroup_count": 56
            },
            "agegroup_F": {
                "Location Not Known": 7,
                "Main Gate Area": 8,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 7,
                "Live! Lagoon": 8,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 9,
                "Private Domain": 2,
                "Thrill Zone": 9,
                "Cabana Suites": 2,
                "Island": 8,
                "Chat Creek": 3,
                "Family Slides": 1,
                "Virtual Village": 7,
                "Unknown Location": 6,
                "agegroup_count": 77
            },
            "agegroup_G": {
                "Location Not Known": 2,
                "Main Gate Area": 5,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 3,
                "Live! Lagoon": 3,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 8,
                "Private Domain": 2,
                "Thrill Zone": 7,
                "Cabana Suites": 4,
                "Island": 7,
                "Chat Creek": 5,
                "Family Slides": 1,
                "Virtual Village": 7,
                "Unknown Location": 5,
                "agegroup_count": 59
            },
            "gender_count": 1390
        },
        "gender_all": {
            "agegroup_A": {
                "Location Not Known": 1,
                "Main Gate Area": 9,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 3,
                "Live! Lagoon": 9,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 7,
                "Private Domain": 7,
                "Thrill Zone": 5,
                "Cabana Suites": 7,
                "Island": 1,
                "Chat Creek": 6,
                "Family Slides": 6,
                "Virtual Village": 1,
                "Unknown Location": 9,
                "agegroup_count": 71
            },
            "agegroup_B": {
                "Location Not Known": 2,
                "Main Gate Area": 2,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 2,
                "Live! Lagoon": 3,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 8,
                "Private Domain": 6,
                "Thrill Zone": 9,
                "Cabana Suites": 5,
                "Island": 5,
                "Chat Creek": 3,
                "Family Slides": 5,
                "Virtual Village": 9,
                "Unknown Location": 5,
                "agegroup_count": 64
            },
            "agegroup_C": {
                "Location Not Known": 3,
                "Main Gate Area": 2,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 6,
                "Live! Lagoon": 7,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 8,
                "Private Domain": 3,
                "Thrill Zone": 8,
                "Cabana Suites": 9,
                "Island": 5,
                "Chat Creek": 9,
                "Family Slides": 9,
                "Virtual Village": 7,
                "Unknown Location": 5,
                "agegroup_count": 81
            },
            "agegroup_D": {
                "Location Not Known": 8,
                "Main Gate Area": 8,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 7,
                "Live! Lagoon": 4,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 5,
                "Private Domain": 4,
                "Thrill Zone": 9,
                "Cabana Suites": 4,
                "Island": 1,
                "Chat Creek": 8,
                "Family Slides": 5,
                "Virtual Village": 4,
                "Unknown Location": 9,
                "agegroup_count": 76
            },
            "agegroup_E": {
                "Location Not Known": 6,
                "Main Gate Area": 9,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 9,
                "Live! Lagoon": 2,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 9,
                "Private Domain": 9,
                "Thrill Zone": 9,
                "Cabana Suites": 5,
                "Island": 1,
                "Chat Creek": 5,
                "Family Slides": 8,
                "Virtual Village": 6,
                "Unknown Location": 7,
                "agegroup_count": 85
            },
            "agegroup_F": {
                "Location Not Known": 5,
                "Main Gate Area": 7,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 4,
                "Live! Lagoon": 4,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 8,
                "Private Domain": 1,
                "Thrill Zone": 2,
                "Cabana Suites": 3,
                "Island": 9,
                "Chat Creek": 7,
                "Family Slides": 8,
                "Virtual Village": 9,
                "Unknown Location": 7,
                "agegroup_count": 74
            },
            "agegroup_G": {
                "Location Not Known": 8,
                "Main Gate Area": 5,
                "Food & Beverage Area": 8,
                "Live! Lagoon": 1,
                "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 7,
                "Private Domain": 5,
                "Thrill Zone": 8,
                "Cabana Suites": 3,
                "Island": 8,
                "Chat Creek": 4,
                "Family Slides": 1,
                "Virtual Village": 7,
                "Unknown Location": 8,
                "agegroup_count": 73
            },
            "gender_count": 1839
        }
    }
```

I need to format it using a mysqli_query that I've made in my PHP script. The reason the above object is invalid is because it's currently using hard-coded data. The data looks like this:

[image: mysql query result]

My code so far:

```
$locationdata_query = 'SELECT gp.gender, gp.agegroup, lz.zonename, lz.loczoneid as zoneid, count(*) as count
                       FROM vantage_local.guests g
                       JOIN vantage_local.guests_personal gp
                       ON g.gid = gp.gid
                       JOIN vantage_local.location_zones lz
                       ON g.loczoneid = lz.loczoneid
                       GROUP BY gp.gender, gp.agegroup, lz.zonename, lz.loczoneid
                       ORDER BY gp.gender DESC, gp.agegroup, lz.zonename';

foreach(mysqli_query($sqlhandle, $locationdata_query) as $data) {
  $counts[]     = array($data['zonename'] => $data['count']);
}

$age = [];
array_push($age, '-');

foreach (mysqli_query($sqlhandle, 'SELECT DISTINCT age_group FROM vantage_local.age_groups') as $agegroup) {
  $age[] = $agegroup['age_group'];
}

foreach($genders as $gender) {
  $gender_counter = 0;
  foreach($age as $agegroup) {
    $agegroup_counter = 0;
    foreach($counts as $zonecount) {
      foreach($zonecount as $zone => $count) {
      }
      $agegroup_val = $locationdata['gender_'.$gender]['agegroup_'.$agegroup][$zone] = (int) $count;
      $agegroup_counter += $agegroup_val;
    }
    $agegroup_totals = $locationdata['gender_'.$gender]['agegroup_'.$agegroup]['agegroup_count'] = $agegroup_counter;
    $gender_counter += $agegroup_totals;
  }
  // get total answered (male, female, and nonbinary)
  if ($gender === 'answered') {
    $gender_counter = $locationdata['gender_female']['gender_count']
      + $locationdata['gender_male']['gender_count']
      + $locationdata['gender_nonbinary']['gender_count'];
  }

  // get total
  if ($gender === 'all') {
    $gender_counter = $locationdata['gender_answered']['gender_count']
      + $locationdata['gender_unanswered']['gender_count'];
  }
  $locationdata['gender_'.$gender]['gender_count'] = $gender_counter;
}
```

The original code with hard coded data looks similar but has one less nested loop and the value being set is just a random number between 1 and 9. For some reason, I can't get the appropriate values to map to the right groupings/categories. They all have the same 13 values for each agegroup eg:

```
 "Family Slides": 4,
 "Food & Beverage Area": 1,
 "Island": 1,
 "Location Not Known": 1,
 "Main Gate Area": 2,
 "Reply Racers / Drop Slides": 1,
 "Thrill Zone": 5,
 "Live! Lagoon": 1,
 "Private Domain": 3,
 "Virtual Village": 1,
 "agegroup_count": 30246
```

Comment: `foreach($zonecount as $zone => $count) {` effectively does nothing, and later you reference `$count` from there, which will always have the same value.

Comment: Ok, I had 
$agegroup_val = $locationdata['gender_'.$gender]['agegroup_'.$agegroup][$zone] = (int) $count;
$agegroup_counter += $agegroup_val;
inside of that block originally but it return the same result. I am well aware that it is always the same value, how do I make it have the correct value?